# PHP Url Routing separate Dir

Tags: php, url, routes

I'm looking for a PHP router for my website and I have my files in the root directory; For example: index.php, details.php, signup.php, recover.php

So I want details.php, signup.php and recover.php in a directory named pages and then to access the links instead on mysite.com/details.php to mysite.com/details or mysite.com/?page=details... I realy want to put them in a separate folder than root.

Thanks everyone !

Answer (score 0):

You simply want an MVC.
I highly suggest you to follow this tutorial series. No frameworks used, yet working.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OsCTzGASImQ&list=PLfdtiltiRHWGXVHXX09fxXDi-DqInchFD

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a script years ago, and I think it might well suit your needs.

### Notes:

- The script is controlled by the pattern *location* at the top.
  I modified it (just inserted **pages/** in the pattern) to suit your case, I hope.
- You could replace all the files you want to move down to the directory *page* by this script - without any modification.
- The script handles most of the URI elements automatically, including port numbers. But: it does not handle log-in credentials (username and password) as many modern browsers and servers do not honor these.
- Also this script is copyrighted it is freeware. So you are allowed to use it in non-commercial and commercial environments.

### Code

```
    <?php
    /*
     ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Redirector Script
     Copyright (C) 2008, methodica.ch, http://www.methodica.ch
     Purpose: Redirect GET request according the pattern 'location'
     Pattern variables (embraced in curly brackets):
       prot: Protocol (i.e. http | https)
       host: Hostname (e.g. www.example.org)
       port: Portnumber (80 | 443 | 81)
       path: Path to the file (includes trailing '/', might be empty)
       file: Filename
       quer: Query, GET parameters (e.g. 'id=myId&mode=1&close=automatic')
     Other text is taken literally
     ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    define('location','{prot}://{host}{port}/{path}pages/{file}{quer}');

    // Do not modify the code below! -------------------------------------------

    // Get URI elements
    $prot = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) && (strtoupper($_SERVER['HTTPS']) == 'ON')) ? 'https' : 'http';
    $server_name = getenv('SERVER_NAME');
    $script_url  = $prot . '://' . $server_name . ':' . getenv('SERVER_PORT') . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $xres = preg_match_all('%^(http[s]{0,1})://(.*?):[\d]*?/(.*/)*(.*)$%i', $script_url, $res, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

    if (($xres!==false) && ($xres>0)) {
        // Prepare variables
        $prot = $res[1];
        $host = $res[2];
        $path = $res[3];
        $file = $res[4];
        $quer = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
        $xport = getenv('SERVER_PORT');
        $port = ($prot=='https') ? ( ($xport=='443') ? '' : ":$xport" ) : ( ($xport=='80') ? '' : ":$xport" );
        $location = location;
        // Replace variable references in pattern
        preg_match_all('/\{.*?\}/i', $location, $res, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($res[0]); $i++) {
            $varname = str_replace(array('{','}'),'',$res[0][$i]);
            $srce = $res[0][$i];
            $dest = $$varname;
            if (is_array($dest)) $dest = ($dest[0]);
            if ($srce=='{quer}') $dest = '?'.$dest; 
            $location = str_replace($srce,$dest,$location);
        }
        // Send redirection header
        header("Location: $location");
        exit();
    } else {
        // Something went awfully wrong
        echo "ERROR: Cannot parse URI:<br />'$script_url'";
        exit();
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works but in the url field on the browser it's displayed the whole path ex: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/pages/details.php

Comment: That's right, as always when a redirect via browser is issued. And, why does it matter? Should the user not see that he/she has been redirected? If this were the case a script would have to transparently pass thru the request and return the result to the user as its own result. This can be done - but I'd not suggest to do it, as it is an overhead. Every requests for elements moved to the _pages_ directory - also for pictures, etc. would be a 2-step access.

Comment: Another alternative would be to install kind of a "reversed" proxy which would filter the requests and do the pass thru for configured URLs. Such solutions exist (hardware + software) and are quite costly. To write such a proxy from scratch however would be a project itself.

Comment: And, lastly, redirection rules an be set in a **.htaccess** file in the root directory. These redirects would also be shown in the browser's URL field.